# Grab within from Curl

Tags: php, curl, stripping

I curl and get the following:

```
echo $contents
```

which gives me this:

```
 <td class="fomeB1" >Balance: $ 1.02</td>

$13.32 fee
$15.22 fee 2
```

How do I just grab the 1.02 - everything after the $ and in front of the `</td>`

I want to strip this via php and put the money into variable $balance....

Any kind of help I can get on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Pretty sure curl is for getting data from a webpage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can use exactly what u want

```
preg_match("/(?<=Balance: ).*?(?=<)/", "<td class='fomeB1'>Balance: $ 1.02</td>", $match);
print_r(str_replace("$"," ",$match));

// Prints:
Array
(
    [0] =>   1.02
)
```

Comment: I think he wants the actual value 1.02 into an array.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a bad way of doing it... but

```
$pieces = explode("$ ", $contents);
$pieces = explode("</td>", $pieces[1]);
$balance = $pieces[0];
```

Or you can use a regular expression. Something like this:

```
\$\s\d+.{1}\d+
```

You can test the regular expression here: [RegExpPal](http://regexpal.com/)

You can use preg_match() to parse the balance using the regular expression.
[preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but What if I have more than $ on that page... can we just find the ones with the word balance in front of it?

Comment: yea with a regular expression

Comment: I am not smart enough to understand how/what to do with the regular expression, can you please provider more guidance?

Answer (score 1):

Basically now you have a string

```
$str = '<td class="fomeB1" >Balance: $ 1.02</td>';
```

Am I right ?

now try this :

```
$txt = getTextBetweenTags($str, "td");
echo $txt;//Balance: $ 1.02
```

Now, use explode:

```
$pieces = explode($txt,' $ ');
echo $pieces[0]; //Balance:
echo $pieces[1]; //1.02
```

`UPDATE:`
try this, it should work if explode works for a string:

```
$pieces = explode("Balance: $ ", $str);
$pieces = explode("</td>", $pieces[1]);
$balance = $pieces[0]; //1.02
```

Comment: do you know the position of balance then , if it'll be always the first `$` you want ?

Comment: I have updated the question up top... the $ that I want always have the Balance: in front of it.... others don't have the word "Balance:"

Comment: are they also in between td tags ? if not then the code I've written should be helpful

Comment: Yes other $ are also in TD as well, but this one in TD and also have the word Balance: in front of it

Comment: yes it does, but the webpage i curl has a lot of td's and $  - your method does work but it's very messy because of all the other tds....

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '<td class="fomeB1" >Balance: $ 1.02</td>';  
$r1 = preg_replace('/.*?\$[ ](.*?)<.*/', '\1',  $str); //match between after first '$ ' ,and first '<' ;
echo $r1; //1.02
```

or

```
$r2= preg_replace('/^<td class="fomeB1" >Balance\: \$ (.*?)<\/td>$/', '\1',  $str); //match between after <td class="fomeB1" >Balance: $    and </td>

echo $r2; //1.02
```

or update

```
$str = ' <td class="fomeB1" >Balance: $ 1.02</td>

$13.32 fee
$15.22 fee 2';  

$r1 = preg_replace('/.*?\$[ ](.*?)<.*/s', '\1',  $str); //match between after first '$ ' ,and first '<' ;
echo $r1.'<br>'; //1.02
```